# Finding common prime divisors in two sets of numbers quickly

Tags: c++, math, optimization, primes

I've been trying to crack this problem: https://codility.com/programmers/task/common_prime_divisors/

I have it functioning in terms of returning correct answers but it's incredibly slow for larger numbers, I wanted to see if anyone has a better taken on doing it faster or explaining ways I can optimize it.

```
bool IsPrime(int number)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;    
}

bool GetPrimeFactors(int valueA, int valueB)
{
    if(valueA < 0 || valueB < 0)
        return false;

    int max = sqrt(std::max(valueA, valueB)) + 1;//sqrt(std::max(valueA, valueB));
    std::vector<int> factors;
    bool oneSuccess = false;
    for(int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
    {
        bool remainderA = valueA % i == 0;
        bool remainderB = valueB % i == 0;
        if(remainderA != remainderB)
            return false;
        if(IsPrime(i))
        {
            //bool remainderA = valueA % i == 0;
           // bool remainderB = valueB % i == 0;

            if(remainderA != remainderB )
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if(!oneSuccess && remainderA && remainderB)
            {
                oneSuccess = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int solution(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B) {
    int count = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        int valA = A[i];
        int valB = B[i];

        if(GetPrimeFactors(valA, valB))
            ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: The `IsPrime` function can use a table lookup of common prime numbers.  If the number is greater than the largest prime, then begin the sieve (and append new found primes to the table).  Usually, a table lookup is faster than the sieve.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You do not actually have to find the prime factors of the numbers to decide if they have the same prime factors.

Here is a general algorithm that I thought up for checking if `a` and `b` have the same prime factors.  This will be much quicker than prime factoring `a` and `b`.

1. If `a == b`, the answer is `true`.
2. If `a == 1 || b == 1`, the answer is `false`.
3. Use [Euclid's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to find the GCD of the 2 numbers.  If the `GCD == 1`, the answer is `false`.
4. Note that the `GCD` will need to contain all of the prime factors of both numbers for the answer to be true, so check if `newa = a/GCD` and `newb = b/GCD` can be reduced to 1 by repeatedly dividing them by `Euclid(newa, GCD)` and `Euclid(newb, GCD)` until  `newa` and `newb` reach `1` which is success, or `Euclid(newa, GCD)` or `Euclid(newb, GCD)` returns `1` which is a fail.

```
Let's see how this works for a = 75, b = 15:

    1) GCD = Euclid(75, 15) = 15
    2) newa = 75/15 = 5, newb = 15/15 = 1, done with newb
    3) newa = 5/Euclid(5, 15) = 5/5 = 1 success!

How about a = 6, b = 4:

    1) GCD = Euclid(6, 4) = 2
    2) newa = 6/2 = 3, newb = 4/2 = 2
    3) Euclid(newa, 2) = Euclid(3, 2) = 1 fail!

How about a = 2, b = 16:

    1) GCD = Euclid(2, 16) = 2
    2) newa = 2/2 = 1 (that's good), newb = 16/2 = 8
    3) newb = 8/Euclid(8, 2) = 8/2 = 4
    4) newb = 4/Euclid(4, 2) = 4/2 = 2
    5) newb = 2/Euclid(2, 2) = 2/2 = 1 success!
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be fast even for arbitrarily large integers.

Answer (score 2):

One (pretty trivial) optimization (**UPDATED**):

```
bool IsPrime(int number)
{
    if (number % 2 == 0) 
    {
        return (number == 2);
    }
    int limit = sqrt(number);
    for (int i = 3; i <= limit; i += 2)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: `if (number % 2 == 0) { return number == 2; }`  Two is prime; other even numbers are not.

Comment: @rossum, my code (before the edit) returns `true` for `2`, as it should. However, I included your suggestion, because it is more efficient (it doesn't calculate `sqrt` for `2`). Thank you!

Comment: @WillNess, didn't have a chance to test it, there was a mistake in the `for` loop condition. Thank you! I've fixed the code.

Answer (score 1):

Java implementation base on [vacawama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34252571/6405287)'s answer:

```
  class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A, int[] B) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            if(A[i] == B[i]) count++;
            else if(A[i] == 1 || B[i] == 1) continue;
            else{
                int GCD = gcd(A[i], B[i]);
                
                if(GCD == 1) continue;
                
                int newA = A[i]/GCD;
                int newB = B[i]/GCD;
                
                if(checkDiv(newA, GCD) && checkDiv(newB, GCD)) count++;
            } 
        }
        
        return count;
    }
    
    public boolean checkDiv(int num, int gcd){
        
        if(num == 1) return true;
        else if(gcd == 1) return false;
        
        else {
            gcd = gcd(gcd, num);
            num = num/gcd;
        
            return checkDiv(num, gcd);
        }
    }
    public int gcd(int a, int b){
        if(b == 0) return a;
        else return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found nice and very detailed explanation [here](http://codility-lessons.blogspot.com/2015/03/lesson-10-commonprimedivisors.html):

Suppose two number `N` and `M`, and factorize them by prime numbers, and then express the GCD of `N` and `M` as `P1 * P2 * P3 * P4 * ... Px` (each of these are prime divisors of `gcd(N,M)`). Then , express `N / gcd(N,M)` and `M / gcd(N,M)` as `N1 * N2 * N3 * ... Ny`, and `M1 * M2 * M3 * ... Mz`, by their prime divisors respectively; then, `N` and `M` can be expressed as below.

```
N = (P1 * P2 * P3 ... Px) * N1 * N2 * N3 * ... Ny
M = (P1 * P2 * P3 ... Px) * M1 * M2 * M3 * ... Mz
```

Since `(P1 * P2 * P3 ... Px)` is the `gcd(N,M)`, Any prime divisor common to `N` and `M` is always appear at least once among `(P1, P2, P3, ... Px)`.

In other words, if any prime divisor of '`N/ gcd(N,M)`' `(N1, N2, N3 ... Ny)` can't be found among `(P1, P2, P3, ...Px)`, it is not a prime divisor of `M`. Thus, it can be said that the set of prime divisors of `N` and `M` are not exactly the same.

Similarly, if any prime divisor of '`M / gcd(A,B)`' `(M1, M2, L3 ... Ly)` can't be found among `(P1, P2. P3, ... Px)`, it is not a prime divisor of `N` and it can be said that the set of prime divisors of `N` and `M` are not exactly the same.

So the problem is just to check if any of `N1-Ny` and `M1-Mz` never appears in `P1-Px`.

Now let's think of this. Let `X = N / gcd(N,M)` and consider `gcd(gcd(N, M), X)`.

For now, it will be as follows.

```
gcd(N,M): P1 * P2 * P3 ... Px
X       : N1 * N2 * N3 ... Ny
```

If `gcd(N,M) % X == 0`, then all the prime divisors of `X` is included in `gcd(N,M)`.

If not, then we compute `gcd(gcd(N,M), X)`. If the gcd of these two values are just 1, that means none of `N1-Ny` appears in `P1-Px`; which means the value `N` have a prime divisor that is not shared with `M`.

If the gcd larger than 1. then we compute `X / gcd(gcd(N,M), X)`, and update `X` with this for the next round. This means we took out some of prime divisors of `X`, which constitutes `gcd(gcd(N,M), X)`, and use it for the next round

If `gcd(N, M) % X == 0` at this point, that means all the prime divisors of `X` is included in `gcd(N, M)`. If not, we do the same thing again as above.

Answer (score 0):

A python implementation for @vacawama solution above.

```
def gcd_division(a, b):
    if not a%b:
        return b
    return gcd_division(b, a%b)

def prime_reduce(n, gcd):
    na = n // gcd
    ngcd = gcd_division(na, gcd)
    if na == 1:
        return True # success base case
    elif ngcd == 1:
        return False
    return prime_reduce(na, ngcd)

def solution(A, B):
    Z = len(A)
    result = 0
    for i in range(0, Z):
        a, b = A[i], B[i]
        if a == b:
            result += 1
        else:
            gcd = gcd_division(a, b)
            result += (prime_reduce(a, gcd) and prime_reduce(b, gcd))
    return result
```

I ran it with the following test cases.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_cases = (
        (1, ([15, 10, 9], [75, 30, 5]) ),
        (2, ([7, 17, 5, 3], [7, 11, 5, 2]) ),
        (2, ([3, 9, 20, 11], [9, 81, 5, 13]) ),
    )
    for expected, args in test_cases:
        got = solution(*args)
        print('result', expected, got)
        assert(expected == got)
```

Its 100% https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training7KRXR3-FE5/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript solution using @vacawama's answer. 100% on codility

```
function solution(A, B) {

    function getGcd(a,b, res = 1) {
        if (a === b) return res * a;
        if (a % 2 === 0 && b % 2 === 0) return getGcd(a/2, b/2, 2 * res);
        if (a % 2 === 0) return getGcd(a/2, b, res);
        if (b % 2 === 0) return getGcd(a, b/2, res);
        if (a > b) return getGcd(a-b, b, res);
        else return getGcd(a, b-a, res);
    }

    const hasCommonPrimeDivisors = (a, b) => {
        if (a === b) return true;
        if (a === 1 || b === 1) return false;
        let gcd = getGcd(a, b);
        if (gcd === 1) return false;
        while (a !== 1 || b !== 1) {
            let newGcd;
            if (a !== 1) {
                newGcd = getGcd(a, gcd);
                if (newGcd === 1) {
                    return false;
                }
                a = a / newGcd;
            }

            if (b !== 1) {
                newGcd = getGcd(b, gcd);
                if (newGcd === 1) {
                    return false;
                }
                b = b/newGcd;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    let count = 0
    A.forEach((a, index) => {
        const b = B[index];
        if (hasCommonPrimeDivisors(a, b)) {
            count++;
        }
    })
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each pair (Z pairs in total) of numbers A[i], B[i], the idea is to reduce both A[i] and B[i] with their shared set of prime divisors.

If at the end of this process, the reduced values are not both equal to 1, then the sets of primes composing initially A[i] and B[i] are different.

Here is the python code, achieving O(Z * log(max(A) + max(B))^2) complexity (and O(1) space complexity). The log(max(A) + max(B))^2 part is a little bit hard to see, but it corresponds to the reduction operation.

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if a < b:
        r, s = b, a
    else:
        r, s = a, b
    

    while s > 0:
        r = r % s
        r, s = s, r

    return r


def solution(A, B):
    res = 0

    for i in range(len(A)):
        g = gcd(A[i], B[i])  # set of prime divisors common to A[i] and B[i] is "contained" in g
        A[i] = A[i] // g
        B[i] = B[i] // g

        k = gcd(g, A[i])
        while k > 1:
            A[i] = A[i] // k
            k = gcd(g, A[i])

        k = gcd(g, B[i])
        while k > 1:
            B[i] = B[i] // k
            k = gcd(g, B[i])

        if A[i] == 1 and B[i] == 1:
            res += 1
    
    return res
```